# VSTO C# - Firing event when Outlook connects or disconnects from network

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How to detect when Outlook gets connected to network (or looses connection to network) in an event handler that gets fired when connectivity status changes?

Comment: On a background thread? Or the VSTO thread? If you want to bg it, then you should just check the status using the WMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can use the `InternetGetConnectedState()` Windows API function from wininet.dll.

You can also use `Namespace.ExchangeConnectionMode` property.

Comment: But how to create event that will automatically be fired when connection status changes?  Thanks

Comment: There is no such event. You can fire a timer once a second to check if the condition has changed.